# c# weird reset for all list items after exiting loop,

Tags: c#, arrays, list

i have a 9,9 matrix and i want to check where there is 0 , if i find a 0 i create a 11 size array which hold the place of the 0 ( i and j) and 1-9 numbers
and that will be added to the list, the it will find the next 0 add and soo on.

```
    public static void CheckandCreate()
    {
        int[] sector = new int[11];
        //setting the array to  1-9
        for (int i = 2; i < sector.Length; i++)
        {
            sector[i] = i - 1;
        }
        //looking for 0
        for (int i = 0; i < suduku.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < suduku.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                //finding 0
                if (suduku[i, j] == 0)
                {
                    sector[0] = i;
                    sector[1] = j;
                    sectorlist.Add(sector);
                    Console.WriteLine("Found Empty on " + i + " " + j);
                    //check to see array
                    sectorprinter(sector);
                    //check to if the array is on list and also print from list(check)
                    sectorprinter(sectorlist[sectorlist.IndexOf(sector)]);
                }
            }
            //check to see if its still keeps the same value as before,this is where it failes!
            Console.WriteLine();
            sectorprinter(sectorlist[3]);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sectorlist.Capacity);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

thats the code
and this is the list making:

```
   static List<int[]> sectorlist = new List<int[]>();
```

after all i print all sectors(all arrays)....

this is the output:

```
           Found Empty on 0 1
           0 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           0 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           Found Empty on 0 2
           0 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           0 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           Found Empty on 0 4
           0 4 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           0 4 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           Found Empty on 0 6
           0 6 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           0 6 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           Found Empty on 0 7
           0 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           0 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

           0 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

           Found Empty on 1 0
           1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           Found Empty on 1 1
           1 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           1 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           Found Empty on 1 2
           1 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           1 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           Found Empty on 1 3
           1 3 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           1 3 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           Found Empty on 1 4
           1 4 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           1 4 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           Found Empty on 1 5
           1 5 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           1 5 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           Found Empty on 1 7
           1 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           1 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           Found Empty on 1 8
           1 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           1 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

           1 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

           Found Empty on 2 0
           2 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           2 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           Found Empty on 2 2
           2 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           2 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           Found Empty on 2 3
           2 3 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           2 3 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           Found Empty on 2 4
           2 4 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           2 4 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           Found Empty on 2 5
           2 5 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           2 5 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           Found Empty on 2 8
           2 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           2 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

           2 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

           Found Empty on 3 1
           3 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           3 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           Found Empty on 3 3
           3 3 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           3 3 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           Found Empty on 3 5
           3 5 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           3 5 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           Found Empty on 3 8
           3 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           3 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

           3 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

           Found Empty on 4 0
           4 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           4 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           Found Empty on 4 1
           4 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           4 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           Found Empty on 4 2
           4 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           4 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           Found Empty on 4 3
           4 3 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           4 3 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           Found Empty on 4 5
           4 5 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           4 5 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           Found Empty on 4 6
           4 6 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           4 6 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           Found Empty on 4 7
           4 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           4 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           Found Empty on 4 8
           4 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           4 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

           4 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

           Found Empty on 5 0
           5 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           5 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           Found Empty on 5 3
           5 3 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           5 3 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           Found Empty on 5 5
           5 5 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           5 5 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           Found Empty on 5 7
           5 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           5 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

           5 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

           Found Empty on 6 0
           6 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           6 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           Found Empty on 6 3
           6 3 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           6 3 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           Found Empty on 6 4
           6 4 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           6 4 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           Found Empty on 6 5
           6 5 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           6 5 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           Found Empty on 6 6
           6 6 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           6 6 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           Found Empty on 6 8
           6 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           6 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

           6 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

           Found Empty on 7 0
           7 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           7 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           Found Empty on 7 1
           7 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           7 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           Found Empty on 7 3
           7 3 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           7 3 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           Found Empty on 7 4
           7 4 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           7 4 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           Found Empty on 7 5
           7 5 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           7 5 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           Found Empty on 7 6
           7 6 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           7 6 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           Found Empty on 7 7
           7 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           7 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           Found Empty on 7 8
           7 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           7 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

           7 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

           Found Empty on 8 1
           8 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           Found Empty on 8 2
           8 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           Found Empty on 8 4
           8 4 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 4 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           Found Empty on 8 6
           8 6 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 6 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           Found Empty on 8 7
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

           64

           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           8 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           Press any key to continue . . .
```

WHAT WENT WRONG?!

Comment: Have you tried single-stepping through your code in the debugger?

Comment: At least describe all of the avenues you have already explored, and why you're still stumped after that good-faith effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
sectorlist.Add(sector);
```

it is adding a reference to the `sector` array rather than a copy of the array. Because you subsequently modify that array, it will also modify the one you added to `sectorlist`, since they are the same array.

To fix this, make a copy of the array and add the copy to `sectorlist`:

```
sectorlist.Add(sector.ToArray());
```

I'm not saying your code will work correctly after that change, but it will at least fix that particular bug.

Other than that, I recommend single-stepping through the code in the debugger.